# How do i set up a label so that when a button is pressed then it will change that value displayed on the label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uilabel

How do i set up a label so that when a button is pressed then it will change that value displayed on the label and set it up that each time a button is pressed it they will all just add to the previous number that was pressed - and is it possible to set up 2 view scenes on the same view controller?

```
    @IBOutlet weak var creditLabel: UILabel!

    var savedNum:Int = "Credits: /0"

    var Money : Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBAction func oneDollar(_ sender: Any) {
        let oneDollar = 1
    }

    @IBAction func fiveDollars(_ sender: Any) {
        let fiveDollars = 5
    }

    @IBAction func tenDollars(_ sender: Any) {
        let tenDollars = 10
    }
    @IBAction func twentyDollars(_ sender: Any) {
        let twentyDollars = 20
    }
    @IBAction func fiftyDollars(_ sender: Any) {
        let fiftyDollars = 50
    }
    @IBAction func oneHundredDollars(_ sender: Any) {
        let oneHundredDollars = 110
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - it looks like you've hooked up 6 buttons - where are you trying to update the label?

Comment: In each of you IBActions, increment money: `money += 5`, then update the label with the new number: `creditLabel.text = "Credits: \(money)"`.

Comment: This doesn't compile - `var savedNum:Int = "Credits: /0"`. Don't show unnecessary code (e.g. `didReceiveMemoryWarning`). What does `var userName: UILabel` have to do with your question? Please update your question to show valid, _relevant_ code. Please take a read of [Ask]

Comment: Thanks -   so would the  IBAction look this                                      @IBAction func oneDollar(_ sender: Any) {
    money += 1}

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is something like this…

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var creditLabel: UILabel!

    var credit = 0 {
       didSet {
           creditLabel.text = "Credit: $\(credit)"
       }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        credit = 0
    }


    @IBAction func oneDollar(_ sender: Any) {
        credit += 1
    }

    @IBAction func fiveDollars(_ sender: Any) {
        credit += 5
    }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: thanks I'm getting an error saying "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT  on this line: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Answer (score -1):

Is your Label connected to your UIViewController? What about the corresponding actions? Are you connecting the same actions to the same button? Need more information to help solve your error that's being thrown.

Comment: If you require clarification from the OP, please add as a comment to the question, not as an answer.